# JQuery + JCrop issue in DotNetNuke

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dotnetnuke, jcrop

I am using dnn 6. It has file  dotnetnuke/js/dnn.jquery.js so I created a module and added reference to this jquery file and all others JCrop files and it doesn't work.
So I added official JQuery.js but then dnn can't find some methods.
Is there anybody who has used JCrop with DotNetNuke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reference jQuery from DotNetNuke, call [`DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration()`](http://dotnetnukeru.com/Dnn6Docs/api/html/M_DotNetNuke_Framework_jQuery_RequestRegistration.htm).  This will use the shared jQuery reference (so that jQuery is on the page exactly once, in the `<head/>`, regardless of how many extensions ask for it).

If you're using jQuery 6.1, you should use the [Client Resource Management API](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3191/Enhancements-for-working-with-JavaScript-and-CSS-files-in-DNN-6-1.aspx) to request other scripts, with something like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>

<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/MyModule/js/jquery.jcrop.js" />
```